# Is += faster than -=?

Tags: c++, performance

Full disclosure - I was inspired by [Is x += a quicker than x = x + a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479486/is-x-a-quicker-than-x-xa)

That aside, I decided to test `+=` vs `-=`. Simple tests reveal they're about the same. Then I tried something similar to:

```
std::vector<int> x;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++)
   x.push_back(rand()%10);
```

and call `+=` and `-=` proportionally to a given number:

```
long long sum = 0;

for ( each number in the array )
    if ( x[j] < k )
        sum += x[j];
    else
        sum -= x[j];
```

so, if `k` is, say, small, `-=` would get called more often (duuuh). I tried with `k = 2` which would give a higher proportion of `-=` called, and with `k = 5`, which should yield about the same number of `-=` and `+=`.

The punchline: calling `-=` is about twice as faster than calling `+=`. Why would it be more efficient in this case?

Comment: I think there are better things to be "inspired" by.

Comment: Probably just a slight advantage to A + B, considering that A - B is just A + (-B)

Comment: Two words: branch prediction. Hint: Try k=8

Comment: One point to take away from this question/answer is that "micro benchmarking" is complicated with modern processors and optimizing compilers. It's rarely as simple as it appears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[I'm gonna jump in before Mysticial gets a hold of this and guess: **branch prediction**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)

So, it's not the `-=` vs `+=`.

The condition `x[j] < k` can be better predicted when it's almost always `true` or `false` than it can be when there's about the same number of numbers for which it can evaluate to either.

For `k = 2`, one in 10 will evaluate to `false`.

For `k = 5`, they'll be about the same and distributed randomly, so harder to predict.

EDIT: See http://ideone.com/1PYMl - all extra stuff is there to prevent unused code optimization (the `cout`s).

tl;dr: Results for varying `k`:

```
k: 1 Time: 280
k: 2 Time: 360
k: 3 Time: 440
k: 4 Time: 520
k: 5 Time: 550
k: 6 Time: 510
k: 7 Time: 450
k: 8 Time: 360
k: 9 Time: 260
```

as you can see, the closer `k` gets to a chaotically varying condition, the program takes more. Towards the ends, it takes about half the time.

Comment: so you predict it is about branch prediction

Comment: I was about to say the exact same thing. Also, to answer the main question at hand, on almost all architectures ever, the add and sub instructions _should_ take basically the same time.