# What is "excessive trickness"?

Tags: javascript, terminology

After reading Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and Stoyan Stevanov's "JavaScript Patterns," I'm trying to determine exactly what 'excessive trickiness' means.  They both say that this occours when using either `++` or `--` in your code, but can't find a firm definition for this term, either within SO or via a Google search.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a fairly lengthy discussion with links:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Comment: There are  lot of great answers here and I get it now.  Thanks for thge help from everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hear it from Crockford himself here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=47Ceot8yqeI#t=4140s

The simple answer is that `++` and `--` act on a variable, and usually do it at the same time as you're doing something else to that variable. For example, can you quickly decide what this does?

```
y += x++ + ++y; // what is y now?
```

More StackOverflow discussion: [Why avoid increment ("++") and decrement ("--") operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't know about you, but I can tell you instantly that this saves to code at index 1. And I use Python 80% of the time, that language doesn't even *have* post-/pre-increment/-decrement. Are JS developers unable to memorize the perfectly simple meaning of these operators? Not that side effects in *complex expressions* aren't confusing. But your example seems quite contrieved to me. And many developers in C and C++ seem to get along just fine with these operators, despite using them properly being even harder in C and C++ due to potential of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, it's a contrived example. How about `y += x++ + ++y`?

Comment: That is indeed tricky, I suggest you use that instead. Note that the aforementioned C and C++ developers would agree it's feindish (only partly because it's undefined behaviour in their languages).

Answer (score 1):

It's about the little tricks that are built-in. For example, `avar++` is an alias for `avar = avar + 1`.

JavaScript is filled with operators and other things that make programming easier, but they are just tricks. That's probably what he means.

Also, as Jonathan pointed out: [Why avoid increment ("++") and decrement ("--") operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: ...except that `var` is a reserved word. ;-)

Comment: `avar++` is **not** an alias for `avar = avar = avar + 1`, in expression contexts. `++avar` is. Preincrement changes the variable's value but evaluates to the previous value. Maybe Crockford *is* right...

Answer (score 0):

Excessive trickiness is subjective. Because of that, there's no firm definition for it.

Some would say the C famous string copy code (`while (*p++ = *q++);`) is excessively tricky, some would say it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly lengthy discussion with links:

[Why avoid increment ("++") and decrement ("--") operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript)

I think part of the idea is that when using those operators anywhere but with a single variable on a single line, they become confusing to anyone not in the developer's head.