# Need help understanding the + operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is `1 + + + 1 = 2` in Javascript?

What is this behavior called? Is it documented somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Comment: @Sudhir: Interestingly enough, though, there is no ++ here.

Answer (score 6):

It's because of the spacing. The unary operator `+` can be applied as many times as necessary, and so your expression becomes:

```
1 + (+(+1))
```

That is,

```
1 + 1
```

. Normally, it appears you can't do this, i.e. `1 + ++ 1` will fail, but that's because two `+`s are parsed as a prefix increment which is invalid when not used on a variable. In the same way, `1 +++ 1` fails because it's parsed as `1++ + 1`, and you can't increment `1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's parsed as...

```
1 + (+ (+ 1))
```

...which obviously evaluates to two.