# Incrementally decrease z-index using jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, z-index

How would I incrementally decrease the z-index on a set of div elements using jQuery starting with an index of 999.

I have already seen [other questions about incrementally decreasing z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963740/incremental-countdown-to-change-z-index-value-of-sibling-elements) but it doesn't have a starting z-index for the first element. Modified code from that post is below:

```
$('div.count').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('z-index', $(this).length-i);
});
```

End result should look like:

```
<div class="count" style="z-index:999;"></div>
<div class="count" style="z-index:998;"></div>
<div class="count" style="z-index:997;"></div>
```

Comment: so why not just replace $(this).length with 999 ???

Comment: @roasted that works, but I was wondering if there was other (better) ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell it where to start, and subract one on every iteration :

```
var start = 999;

$('div.count').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('z-index', start--);
});
```

or use the index

```
$('div.count').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('z-index', 999 - i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That will give you a wring z index.Declare a global variable and decrement in loop.

```
var subsection = 999;   
$('div.count').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('z-index', subsection --);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` method..

```
var count = $('div.count').length; 
$('div.count').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('z-index', count - $('div.count').index(this));
});
```

**or**

```
var count = $('div.count').length; 
$('div.count').each(function(i){
   $(this).css('z-index', count - i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = 999;
$('div.count').CSS('z-index', function () {
    return start--;
});
```

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jQuery.com/CSS/).

Answer (score 1):

Following Code will work properly:

```
jQuery('div.count').each(function(i){
  jQuery(this).css('z-index', 999-i);
});
```

The z-index of first element will be 999 and the 999th will be 0...