# Increment on "__toString"

Tags: php, increment, magic-methods

I am not sure what the title should be, but the code should explain it better:

```
class Group {
    private $number = 20;

    public function __toString() {
        return "$this->number";
    }
}

$number = new Group();
echo $number, PHP_EOL;
echo ++ $number, PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

$number = "20";
echo $number, PHP_EOL;
echo ++ $number, PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

$number = 20;
echo $number, PHP_EOL;
echo ++ $number, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
20
20              <--- Expected 21

20
21

20
21
```

Any idea why I got `20` instead of `21`? Even then the code below works:

```
$i = null ;
echo ++$i ; // output 1
```

I know `Group` is an object that implements `__toString` , i expected `++` to work with the string from `__toString` or at least `throw an error`

Comment: Does PHP offer a way to overload the increment operators? Since your class doesn't easily convert to a number type, you probably have to tell PHP what you want ++ to do.

Comment: if you declare $number not private in the Group class and then try echo ++ $number->number, PHP_EOL;  works?

Comment: Nope .. but that was  increment on string  and even if otherwise .. i should get an error

Comment: Prefix ops like `++` work on variables. But `$number` is an expression in case 1, not a variable`

Comment: @mario then it should be treated as a bug ... I should at least get a warning or notice just like when you try to use `int` with `__toString`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The order in which the operations happen is important:

1. The variable will be fetched as an object, it won't be casted to an integer (or something else).
2. This `++` operator increments the `lval` (the long value) of the `zval`, but does normally nothing else. The object pointer remains the same. The internal `(fast_)increment_function` will be called with the `zval` which has a pointer to the object, which checks for the type first. If it's an object, it does nothing. So when your `zval` is an object, it is as useful as a no-operation. This won't output any warning.
3. Only then the echo instruction performs a string cast on his arguments: The `__toString` method is called and returns `20`.
4. `20` will be output.

Answer (score 9):

To answer you question with a little bit of code.

```
$number = new Group();
echo gettype($number);

$number = "20";
echo gettype($number);

$number = 20;
echo gettype($number);
```

Will result in

```
object
string
integer
```

The three cases:

- You can't do any integer operation on a object, that why your code does not do what you expect. The `__toString` method will called very late, when the acutal output will computed, after you unsuccessfully tried to do an math operation with it.
- You can to math with strings, because PHP internally converts them back to numbers
- Obviously you can do math with integer

**Bonus:**

This will work:

```
$number = new Group();
echo 1 + "$number"; // 21
```

It converts you object into a string, which could be converted into a number for a math operation.

Comment: Adding explicitly one to the variable expression actually opens the way to changing the amount added very easy. Pre- or post-increment operations should be avoided. You'll never really know what will happen. [Douglas Crockford doesn't like them.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript) - and in PHP it's way easier to make use of the short version `$i+=1^` instead of `$i++` - just one more character. And try to increment by 2... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be clearer with just changing the names of the variables like this :

```
class Group {
    private $number = 20;

    public function __toString() {
        return "$this->number";
    }
}

$group = new Group();
echo $group;//print 20 as per your __toString function

++ $group;
```

Now it seems obvious : what is supposed to do a '++' operator on a object of type group ??

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just:

```
class Group {
    private $number = 0;
    public function __construct($number = 0){
        $this->number = intval($number);
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return number_format(++$this->number); // pre-increment
    }
}
$g = new Group();
echo $g; // 1
echo $g; // 2
```

I use something like this to format offsets in tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more feasible than you may think -- just need to do a little bit more type casting, as follows:

```
<?php

class Group {
private $number = 20;

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->number; // replace "" w/string cast
    }
}

$number = (int)(string) new Group();
echo $number, PHP_EOL;
echo ++$number, PHP_EOL;
```

---

You don't have to use the string cast of course in the magic __toString() but I personally prefer to read the code that way rather than seeing the quotes -- but I think that's just a stylistic preference.

Casting the newly created object as a string causes the magic __toString method to automatically execute and it returns a numeric string which when cast to an int allows you to display the number, increment it and display it again.

Incidentally, the space between ++ and $number is okay; I closed it up b/c that is what I'm used to in other languages like C.