# How javascript(ECMAScript) assignment operator works

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

When I initialize an array, I found a weird situation.

**JS code:**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(var i=0, arr2=[]; i < 5; arr2[i] = arr[i++])
    console.log(arr2, i);
```

**Output:**

```
[] 0
[1] 1
[1, 2] 2
[1, 2, 3] 3
[1, 2, 3, 4] 4
```

`arr2` initializes to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] this is what i want

Look at this piece of code :

```
for(var i=0, arr2=[]; i < 5; arr2[i++] = arr[i])
    console.log(arr2, i);
```

This code initializes `arr2` to `[2, 3, 4, 5, undefined]`

i thought `++` operator operates before next line and both code will be same.

But, it operates differently. Why does this happen?

add explanation

I thought both for loop operates like this

```
var i = 0;
var arr2 = [];
check i < 5
console.log(arr2, i);

arr2[i] = arr[i];
i = i + 1;

check i < 5
....skip
```

is this thought wrong?

what is differance between

```
'arr2[i] = arr[i++];' and
'arr2[i++] = arr[i];'
```

Comment: How is this weird? you're console logging i after the array..

Comment: You have weird `for` loops with 4 arguments.

Comment: [Interesting Reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript)

Comment: Logging `arr2` and `i` after the loop has completed makes things a lot clearer

Comment: Can you repeat this behavior without a loop?

Comment: I expanded my answer to your request for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: *removed code snippet because the question code is now fixed*

Now, the issue at hand for your question is not the prefix or postfix notation, but the fact that the expression of the for loop (specifically the 
`arr2[i] = arr[i++]` part) will be executed **AFTER** the loop cycle is completed. This is why your `arr2` array is empty in the first iteration, the indexes are all fine but the assignment has just not happened yet.

The complete `for` syntax as decribed per [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
    statement
```

with the note for `[final-expression]`:

> An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.

To expand on your edited question regarding postfix position difference:

`i++` will increment `i` after its next usage. So, assuming a starting value of `i=3` means

```
arr[i] = arr2[i++] --> arr[3] = arr2[3]
```

and after that is done `i` is incremented to `4`.

In the other way around `i` is incremented after determining the `arr` index, so it already has the incremented value when accessing `arr2`:

```
arr[i++] = arr2[i] --> arr[3] = arr2[4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer :)
I thought `=` operator evaluate values right to left because right value is assign to left...
is this wrong?

Comment: @AndrewLee Yes and no. They're all operators, they will be executed according to operator precedence. And while `=` has a right-to-left associativity, `++` simply has a higher precedence and will be executed before that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence for reference.

Answer (score -1):

If your intent is to copy `arr` to `arr2`, there is no need to iterate over each element. Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var arr2 = arr.slice();
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but doesn't answer the question, should be a comment instead.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia You may want to read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels) that discusses the way to proceed in a similar situation.

Comment: Exactly, I suppose you should have asked him why he needed to do it that way.