# jsLint for loop declaration

Tags: javascript, jslint

According to jsLint it is recommended to declare for loop in the following way:

```
for(var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i+=1){...}
```

What is the difference between `i++` and `i+=1` in this context?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Where does JSLint say this?

Comment: Douglas Crawford hates ++ - that's why jslint tells you to use an extra character in your code - seriously, in this context the only reason not to use ++ is because Douglas Crawford says not to!

Comment: JSLint can be really odd. Consider trying an alternative like JSHint.

Comment: Weirdly answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript) (not the answers, the question itself)

Comment: Ok, I see. But is there any reason to hate ++?

Comment: @andrey As long as you understand what you are doing there as absolutely no reason.

Comment: jslint wont tolerate a `for` loop unless you tell it to, nor will it like `for(` .. it has to be `for (` ... Douglas Crawford has lost it in his old age :p - http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Who is Douglas Crawford?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference. But if you use `i++` you'll save a byte. And if you skip declaring `length` you'll save even more.

So.. I don't see why you'd use it that way. Here's how I always do it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

On the topic of saving bytes here, if your loop looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var e = arr[i];
}
```

You could also do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    var e = arr[i++];
}
```

You could also do this:

```
arr.forEach(function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

This assumes you don't need to use the index of `e`.

Comment: Some bad advice (use `++` because it saves one character; `arr[i++]`), and some good advice (use `forEach`).

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what you're using `i` and `e` for? Why not save a byte?

Answer (score 3):

There is no functional difference in this context. However `++` and `--` can be a source of bugs by complicating code and causing off-by-one errors (preincrement and postincrement confusion). Hence JSLint recommends against using this construct.

JSLint isn't telling you your code is functionally wrong, it's pointing out that there is another way to write it that avoids common pitfalls.

In fact, the latest version of JSLint will recommend against using `for` at all, because array instance methods such as `forEach` and `map` should be preferred (obviously there is a flag to turn this off when necessary).

This and other recommendations are explained in the [JSLint instructions](http://jslint.com/help.html).