# Nested functions, non defined variable-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I found this exercise:

```js
function abc(a){
    return(function(y){
    return y--**--y+1;
  })(++a)+a;
}
document.write(abc(2));
```

The output of that is 7 and I dont understand why, I searched information about nested functions and I didnt found anything....

How is "y" defined?

Comment: y is 3 - does that help?

Comment: or that you are doing `(Math.pow((2 + 1), ((2 + 1) - 1) - 1) + 1) + (2 + 1)`

Comment: `function(y){...}(++a)` is an immediately invoked function expression ... y == ++a or, 3 in this case

Comment: This is less about the nested function and more of the strange math that's going on. Looks like it's using the new `**` operator.

Comment: the question is "how is y defined" - I think IIFE explains that

Comment: While this may be educational, this kind of code should never appear in the wild. Using the `++` and `--` operators like that is [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/971312/5743988).

Comment: Wherever you are learning JavaScript, I'd advise finding somewhere else that explains things before tossing you complicated code like this - ideally only a single concept should be explained per example at least until you have all of the parts down.

Comment: Forget about what`s happening inside the return y--**--y+1; You can add from Right to Left just the (++a)+a this is the only part that gets printed: (1+1+2)1+2 = (1+1+2)3 = (1+1+5) = (1+6) = (7).

Answer (score 2):

this function translates to:

```
//I've replaced the arguments and the vars with the actual values
function abc(){
    function innerFunction(){
        return (3 ** 1) + 1
    }
    return innerFunction(3) + 3
}

//or written differently
function abc(a){
    function innerFunction(v){
        //v--
        var tmp1 = v;
        v = v-1;

        //--v
        v = v-1;
        var tmp2 = v;

        return Math.pow(tmp1, tmp2) + 1;
    }

    a = a+1; //++a
    return innerFunction(a) + a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.
Function abc `return (function(y){ return y--**--y+1; })(++a)+a`
this means if a is 2 `(function(3){ return y--**--y+1; }) + 2`

Answer (score 0):

This contains an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

Here's an example that might clarify how they work:

```
(function(x) {  return x;  })(10);  // Returns 10
```

The value inside the parenthesis is used as the function's argument as soon as the function is defined. So, in this case, the function is set to return the argument, and immediately afterwards, it is given the value `10`.

On your example, with some added whitespace:

```
return (function(y) {
           return y-- ** --y + 1;
       })(++a)
+ a
```

What's happening is the same. A function is being defined then, immediately afterwards, it receives the argument `++a`. It will replace all instances of `y` by the value contained in `++a`. Then, as that is returned, it goes through `+ a`, so it adds `a` to the result.