# i not defined in while loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm trying to add all the numbers for matching arrays and remove the duplicate names. It works for the first instance, but the while loop won't go past Apples.

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {

   function alphabetizer(a, b) {
   if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
   if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
   return 0;
   }

  var newInv = arr1.concat(arr2).sort(alphabetizer);


  for(var i = 0; i < newInv.length; i++) {
    while(newInv[i][1] === newInv[i++][1]) {
      newInv[i] += newInv[i++][0];
      newInv.push([newInv[i][0], newInv[i][1]]);
      newInv.splice(i,2);


   }
  } 

    return newInv;
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"],
    [10, "Apples"]
];

var newInv = [
    [9, "Apples"],
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

It keeps giving me the error `TypeError: newInv[(+ i)] is undefined` But I am not sure why since i is defined, and if I just try to run `newInv[i]` I get the first result.

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/c3j8p2zu/4/)

Comment: You are incrementing `i` two times in the while loop by doing `i++`, you probably don't want to do that. You probably want `i + 1` instead

Comment: When doing that it tells me `i+1` is not defined.

Comment: it's not `i` that is undefined - it's `newInv[i + 1]` - because at the end of the loop i == netInv.length - 1, and i + 1 (newInv[newInv.length]) references an index that doesn't exist in the array ... hence, undefined

Comment: An extra info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're couple places need fix. I updated this jsfiddle

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {

    function alphabetizer(a, b) {
        if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
        if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;

        return 0;    
    }

    var newInv = arr1.concat(arr2).sort(alphabetizer);

    for (var i = 0; i < newInv.length; i++) {
        var j = i;
        while (newInv[j + 1] && newInv[j][1] == newInv[j + 1][1]) {
            newInv[j][0] += newInv[j + 1][0];
            newInv.splice(j + 1, 1);
            j++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newInv.join('<br>');
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"],
    [10, "Apples"]
];

var newInv = [
    [9, "Apples"],
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3j8p2zu/7/

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why the j is needed?

Comment: You're increasing `i` and removing items at same time, which can skip some items in the array, `j` is for recording the old pointer position. And the main issue in the old code is `i++` could be bigger than the length of the array, hence `newInv[i++]` is undefined.