# Decrement class by 1 on click in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have an increment and decrement methods on 2 buttons. My increment function is firing fine however my decrement method is failing. I want to subtract just from the variable so an example would be if I had the class "move2" and fired the decrement method I would get "move1" and so on...d

Any thoughts?

```
let i = 0;

const increment = (div) => {
    document.getElementById(div).classList.remove("move" + i++);
    document.getElementById(div).classList.add("move" + i); 
}

const decrement = (div) => {
    var hasClass = document.getElementById(div).classList.contains('move1', 'move2')
    if(hasClass === true)
        document.getElementById(div).classList.remove("move" + i--);
}
```

Comment: `i++` (increment postfix operator) returns `i`, *then* increments `i`. Similarly with `i--`. If you want to decrement and use the decremented value, use `--i` ( [decrement prefix operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement) )

Comment: What happens when you decrement 0? Does the class become `move-1`?

Comment: `decrement` should be just like `increment`, except you change `++` to `--`.

Comment: `decrement` is missing the `.add()` call.

Comment: See also [Why avoid increment ("++") and decrement ("--") operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/971312)

Comment: @Barmar - FacePalm, thank you

Comment: Except you might want to check whether `i == 0` so it doesn't go negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeMcCaughan mentioned, you need to use `--i` instead of `i--` to use the decremented value on your class name. Also, your current boolean variable `hasClass` returns `true` only if the div has a class of `class1` or `class2`. `class3` and above returns `false` again.

Instead of using `contains()` you can use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead to check the element class name and if it returns true, you can then use the `.classList.replace()` method to update the classname to the decremented value.

```
const decrement = (div) => {
   let className = document.getElementById('x').getAttribute("class"); // get element class value
   let hasClass = className.indexOf('move') >= 0; // returns true if class value has "move" in it
    if(hasClass === true)
      document.getElementById('x').classList.replace((className),("move" + --i));     // replace the class value with the decremented class name
}
```

---

jsFiddle with the above approach: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/rdjv5hsm/11/

---

Also if you want to cap the decrement at 0, you can edit the if condition from:

```
if(hasClass === true) {
    document.getElementById('x').classList.replace((className),("move" + --i));
}
```

To:

```
if(hasClass === true && i > 0) {
    document.getElementById('x').classList.replace((className),("move" + --i));
}
```

jsFiddle with decrement capping: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/rdjv5hsm/14/