# Problem with ++ operator after expression

Tags: javascript

so I have this javascript code:

```js
let version = "v179";
version = (parseInt(version.replace("v","")))++;
console.log("got:",version);
```

but I get this **error**: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`. However it works if I replace the `++` with `+ 1` any idea why it does that? Why can't I use the increment operator for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Polemics here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript best answer said: "My view is to always use ++ and -- by themselves on a single line"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foo++` means "Take the value of foo, add 1, then assign it back to `foo`.

`parseInt(version.replace("v",""))` gives you 179, so you are saying:

`179++` which means "Take the value of 179" (hang on, `179` *is* a value, not something that *has* a value), "add 1 to it and then assign it back to `179`".

So you're trying to say `179=180` which doesn't make sense. You have to assign to a variable (or object property).

Comment: Oh yeah, I see I have forgotten the basics! Thank you! Accepting your post as answer in 8 minutes

Answer (score 3):

`++` only works on lvalues, as it changes the content of a variable. It is roughly (but not completely) equal to `+= 1`, not `+ 1`. Just like how it's meaningless to write

```
(parseInt(version.replace("v",""))) += 1
```

or

```
(parseInt(version.replace("v",""))) = 17
```

it also makes no sense to write

```
(parseInt(version.replace("v","")))++
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `x++` means that increase the value of the variable `x` `1`. Its same as

```
x = x + 1;
x += 1;
```

Now `(parseInt(version.replace("v","")))` will return a value like `179`. So it doesn't make sense to increase it. `++` or `--` is only for variables not for constant values.

You should use `+ 1` to add one to a constant value

```js
let version = "v179";
version = (parseInt(version.replace("v","")))+ 1;
console.log("got:",version);
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally you trying to do next -

```
179++
```

Incremental function will not work that way.
the only way to do it -

```
let version = "v179";
version = parseInt(version.replace("v",""));
version++;
console.log("got:",version);
```